# How to iterate over a list of items from Python/Flask using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, list, flask, iteration

I'm working to create a graph using HTML/JS/Python/Flask and the labels for this line graph should come from a list in Python and then I would use it on a Javascript.

So far I have not been able to successfully iterate over that list in Javascript, I'm getting 4 times the same string on my HTML.

I'm using a code similar to this one:

start.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def home():
    data = ['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL']
    return render_template('index.html', data = data, len = len(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<body>    
   <p id='test'></p>
   <script>
     let text = '';
     for (i=0; i<'{{len}}'; i++){
        text += '{{data | tojson}}[i]' + '<br>'
     }
     console.log(text)
     document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text;
   </script>
</body>
```

I'm getting this as an output:

```
['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL'][i]
['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL'][i]
['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL'][i]
['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL'][i]
```

And I'm looking to get this instead:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
```

The data sent to the Javascript is sent as text and not as a list, if I change this:

```
text += '{{data | tojson}}[i]' + '<br>'
```

To this:

```
text += '{{data | tojson}}'[i] + '<br>'
```

The output becomes:

```
[
"
A
B
```

And the console output is:

```
[<br>"<br>A<br>B<br>
```

Do anybody know how to handle this properly so I get the correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might have noticed, I'm a complete beginner when it comes to Javascript, doing some research, I found out I can slice and split in Javascript as well. So I solved my issue by using those two methods.

Giving more detail about what I did, {{data}} is passed over to Javascript as a single string, as '['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL']', and if you read this string as a console output it shows:

```
[&#39;ABC&#39;, &#39;DEF&#39;, &#39;GHI&#39;, &#39;JKL&#39;]
```

To solve this I first sliced the string with:

```
flask_data = '{{data}}';
temp_array = flask_data.slice(6,-6);
```

So I get this as a result:

```
ABC&#39;, &#39;DEF&#39;, &#39;GHI&#39;, &#39;JKL
```

Then I split the string using the following substring: '', '', as follows:

```
array = temp_array.split('&#39;, &#39;');
```

And as a result I got the array I needed:

```
['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in HTML

```html
<body>    
   <p id='test'></p>
   <script>
     let text = '';
     for (i=0; i<'{{len}}'; i++){
        text += '{{data[i]}}' + '<br>'
     }
     console.log(text)
     document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = text;
   </script>
</body>
```

or you can also pass a string instead of an array.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def home():
    data = ['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL']
    return render_template('index.html', data = "\n".join(data), len = len(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

and then in HTML you can just  print this joined string

```
<body>    
   <p id='test'></p>
   <script>
     document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = {{data}};
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your first suggestion and it didn't work, the console output is: <br><br><br><br>. I din't tried your other suggestions as I need the result to be a list so I can iterate over it in my Javascript.